# Why do Log4Net Filters Receive Messages Outside of the Evaluator Threshold?

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-filter

My log4net config is like this:

```
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <to value="xxx" />
      <from value="xxx" />
      ...
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR"/>
      </evaluator>
      <filter type="MyApp.Logging.EmailLogThrottler">
      </filter>
    </appender>
```

If I set a breakpoint in my `MyApp.Logging.EmailLogThrottler` class, I see it is receiving INFO messages to filter. The EmailLogThrottler is fairly expensive so I only want it to receive ERROR messages, as per the evaluator threshold. Is this possible?

Secondary question - it seems that filters are applied first and then evaluator thresholds (which is counter intuitive to me). Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, set the threshold *directly on the appender* for best performance:

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="xxx" />
  <from value="xxx" />
  ...
  <threshold value="ERROR"/>
```

See [this mailing list post on the difference between threshold and evaluator](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200509.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C7694A9@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E)

### What is the difference between threshold and evaluator?

```
<!-- appender ... -->
<evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
  <threshold value="ERROR"/>
</evaluator>

<threshold value="ERROR" />
```

> Does one discard messages sooner than the other?

### Answer:

> The threshold is different to the evaluator.
>
> The threshold is implemented in the AppenderSkeleton and therefore
>   supported by almost all appenders. It is just a simple test that is
>   used to ignore logging events that have a level below the threshold.
>   The threshold is checked early and as a simple test is very
>   performant.

The post goes on to say this about the Evaluator, which is not intended to filter messages, but instead to trigger sending the buffered messages:

> The Evaluator is a pluggable object that is used by the
>   BufferingAppenderSkeleton to determine if a logging event should not
>   be buffered, but instead written/sent immediately. If the Evaluator
>   decides that the event is important then the whole contents of the
>   current buffer will be sent along with the event. **The evaluator does
>   not function like the threshold or a filter in that it does not
>   discard events.**

It has this to say on filters:

> Filters have a great deal of flexibility because multiple filters can
>   be chained together to provide fine grained control over the events
>   that are output. Because of this they also have a higher cost in terms
>   of performance, each filter in the chain is an object and is asked to
>   decide on the correct course of action.
>
> In the simple case of the
>   threshold filtering the Threshold property should be used in
>   preference to a filter.